# Create a route for any four digit number ie site.com/3434

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to create a route that allows for any four digit number to be passed into the URL (www.site.com/3434).  I've been unable to figure this out from the express docs and am just learning it for the first time.

I pieced together something based on google searches, but it isn't correct and I don't have enough regex knowledge yet.

```
app.get(/^[0-9]{4,4}$/, function(req, res){
  res.render('mobile');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
app.get('/:id([0-9]{4})', function(req, res){
  res.render('mobile');
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I give yours a try but something is still off: http://localhost:8080/5556 results in "Cannot GET /5556"